# In which episodes of Samurai Jack doesn't Jack speak?

Tags: samurai-jack

Samurai Jack is characteristically quiet and minimalist, to the point where Phil LaMarr, the voice actor for Jack, isn't even in all of them:

> There are some episodes that he is in that I'm not in, just because, he didn't speak. I was looking at that on IMDb that the number of episodes produced, and the number I'm credited in, are not the same.
>
> — Phil LaMarr on [I Think You're Interesting, Episode 7](http://www.vox.com/podcasts/2017/4/12/15205304/samurai-jacks-phil-lamarr-voice-age), 2:25

Which episodes are those?

Comment: Hmm.  I thought lists of answers weren't what Stack Exchange was all about.  Well, not like this, anyway?

Comment: @can-ned_food this isn't one of *those* list questions because this is finite and objective. Read ["what is the definition of a list question?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [62 episodes listed in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Samurai_Jack_episodes). IMDB [credits Phil LaMarr with 58](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0482851/). Note that the titles don't always match up for some reason.

Of the 58 episodes LaMarr does, only one does not feature Jack's voice. This gives us 5 episodes he does not speak

1. Episode 3.11 - [Birth of Evil](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0837471/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) While Phil LaMarr is credited for other roles, he never speaks as Jack
2. Episode 3.12 - [Birth of Evil, Part II](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0837472/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm) This episode is about Aku's backstory
3. Episode 4.5 - [The Princess and the Bounty Hunters](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0837474/?ref_=tt_ep_nx) Mostly involved bounty hunters fighting over who will fight Jack
4. Episode 4.11 - [Tale of X.49](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0693974/?ref_=tt_ep_nx) This episode revolves around X49. No other character has dialogue in the episode
5. Episode 4.12 - [Young Jack in Africa](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0837475/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) Revolves around a incident in Jack's childhood. Jack never speaks